# Thymeleaf th:each + spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm a beginner with thymeleaf and Spring MVC.

I try to make a loop with images, but I think my controller return me empty list because when I check on my page it doesn't show my html with th:each.

I make a lot of research and based my code on Spring mvc tutorial : http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html

Here are my code I don't understand my mistake.. I give you all my code hoping you'll find where is my error. I think my error is in my crontroller.
I thank you a lot for your help!

First my java class

```
public class Sponsors {

    private String image;
    private String href;
    private String name;
    private String id;

    public Sponsors(String image,String href,String name,String id) {
        this.image = image;
        this.href = href;
        this.name = name;   
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getHref() {
        return href;
    }

    public void setHref(String href) {
        this.href = href;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here it's just a test to fill an arraylist with some Sponsors

```
public class GetSponsorsList {

    private List<Sponsors> listSponsors = new ArrayList<Sponsors>();

    public GetSponsorsList() {
        listSponsors.add(new Sponsors("@{/images/logo-***.jpg}","@{/recherche?res=***}","****","****"));
        listSponsors.add(new Sponsors("@{/images/logo-***.jpg}","@{/recherche}","****","****"));
        listSponsors.add(new Sponsors("@{/images/logo-***.jpg}","@{/recherche}","*****","*****"));
        listSponsors.add(new Sponsors("@{/images/logo-***.jpg}","@{/recherche}","*****","*****"));
        listSponsors.add(new Sponsors("@{/images/logo-***.jpg}","@{/recherche}","*****","*****"));
    }

    public List<Sponsors> getListSponsors() {
        return listSponsors;
    }

    public void setListSponsors(List<Sponsors> listSponsors) {
        this.listSponsors = listSponsors;
    }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeSponsors extends AbstractController {

    @ModelAttribute("sponsorsList")
    public List<Sponsors> sponsorsList() {
        return new GetSponsorsList().getListSponsors();
    }
}
```

And last this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="sect sect--guide" th:fragment="sponsors-panel_2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 ">
        <p class="t2">...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 ">
        <div class=" col-sm-4 col-xs-12  col-border" th:each="sponsor : ${sponsorsList}">
          <ul class="list list--guide">
            <li>
              <a th:href="${sponsor.href}" target="_blank" id="${sponsor.id}"><h3>...</h3>
                <img th:src="${sponsor.image}" style="width: 100%" alt="" id="LBP"/>
                <span>
                  <img class="arrow arrow-out" th:src="@{/images/i-arrow.svg}" alt=""/>
                  <img class="arrow arrow-over" th:src="@{/images/i-arrow-white.svg}" alt=""/>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your request mapping for this page?

Comment: But I don't use th:href to print my tab. So why should I need a request mapping?

Comment: Try to add @ControllerAdvice annotation in the controller class and set the request mapping in the same controller. Model attribute is only available for requests inside the controller. Using controllerAdvice annotation you will make available for all requests. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanx I'll try this :D

Comment: @Controller
public class HomeSponsors extends AbstractController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "sponsorsList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Sponsors> messages() {
        return new GetSponsorsList().getListSponsors();
    }
}

Comment: I change my controller to this but it doesn't work. I try to input @ControllerAdvise but i can't find any help that I can understand :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edwyn,

What I mean is something like this:

```
@Controller
@ControllerAdvice
public class HomeSponsors extends AbstractController {

    @RequestMapping("/sponsorsPage")
    public String sponsorsPage(Model model) {
        return "sponsorsPage";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("sponsorsList")
    public List<Sponsors> sponsorsList() {
        return new GetSponsorsList().getListSponsors();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry :/ I'll do it.

Comment: `@ControllerAdvice` is for something completely different... Don't add that to a `@Controller`.

Comment: Thank you a lot kimy! It's working now!
I don't know Deinum but if I don't put it, my website doesn't work.

Comment: @M. Deinum It is necesary if you want the model attribute to take effect in all request mapping, even outside this controller

Comment: Then still don't add it to a `@Controller` it should be a separate component, especially not here because there is some `AbstractController` class with who knows what in there and you probably don't want to have that globally applied.